# ¿cual es el String que mas se repite dentro de un vector?

Tags: pseudocódigo

Por ejemplo si tengo un array de n elementos

```
 A ={ Pedro, Juan, Lucas,....., Bruno}
```

Quiero saber cual es el nombre que se repitió mas y menos veces, me quede trabado en esta pregunta ya que me lo pedían en pseudo código, si alguien supiera lo agradecería

Comment: Tendrías que recorrer el array para buscar los elementos únicos, luego con ese array de únicos buscar por cada posición, cuantas veces aparece en el array original y asociar dicha cantidad al nombre, luego ordenas en base a la cantidad y tendrás tu resultado (eso es lo que se me ocurre). Saludos.

Comment: Hola, agrega lo que has realizado por favor, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien, a mí se me ocurrió esto:

- 1 arreglo bidimensional (índice 1: nombre | índice 2: cantidad de veces encontrado).
- 1 arreglo para los nombres.
- 2 ciclos, uno dentro de otro, para la búsqueda de conteo de nombres.
- 1 ciclo y 1 condicional para validar el valor mayor.

1. La primera vuelta comienzas del índice 1 y guardas Pedro. Validas que ese nombre sea igual a los índices posteriores, de esa forma vas contando los "Pedros".
2. En la segunda vuelta comienzas del índice 2, validas si está en el arreglo de los nombres encontrados, y sí. Entonces pasas a la vuelta siguiente.
3. En la siguiente comienzas del índice 3 y así vas repitiendo y guardando los nombres con sus cantidades de veces encontrados.
4. Luego que tengas todos los nombres con sus cantidades de veces encontrados, debes recorrer ese arreglo, empiezas por Pedro, guardas 3, luego María es menor, pasas, luego Raquel es menor, pasas... y así. Si te encontraras a un nombre con conteo mayor, cambias a Pedro y te quedas con el nuevo nombre, pero para el ejemplo, Pedro fue el valor mayor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchas gracias bro no había pensado usar una matriz, gracias por la imagen, me has dado una idea de cómo podría resolverlo, thanks you, saludos 